# Convert data to columns db2

Tags: db2

Rows to Columns

I have a table that stores data in rows rather than column (god knows why. I can't change the table as it is handled by clients.)

The data looks like this

```
CUSTDATA
--------
IdentificaitonId
FirstName
LastName
MiddleName
```

Sample data

```
CUSTDATA
--------
PID4587
FNAME1
LNAME1
MNAME1
PID4589
FNAME2
LNAME2
PID4959
FNAME3
LNAME3
MNAME3
```

`IdentificaitonId` always starts with `'PID'`, e.g. `PID4587`. First and Last Name is mandatory so it is never `NULL` or empty.

Is there any way I can query the table for the following output:

```
IdentificaitonId     FirstName   LastName   MiddleName
PID4587              FNAME1      LNAME1     MNAME1
PID4589              FNAME2      LNAME2     
PID4959              FNAME3      LNAME3     MNAME3
```

Comment: How do you know that `FNAME1` and `LNAME1` belong to `PID4587` and not some other ID?

Comment: Also, how do you ensure rows come out in the order you expect them to?

Comment: @mustaccio Consider it as a given, the PID458 is always followed by First and Last name. Middle is optional so its not present for some of PIDs

Comment: @mustaccio Also none of the names are starting with PID, i checked

Comment: In a relational database table records are not ordered unless you explicitly order them by some criteria; so, what's the criteria?

Comment: @mustaccio: the table was copied from AWD databse. But I need to extact info in desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it finally!

with allrows as(
select csdata.custdata,rownumber() over(order by rrn(csdata)) ROWNO 
from  CUSTDATA csdata
)
select custdata,
( select custdata from allrows b where ROWNO = a.ROWNO + 1)
as FIRST_NAME,
( select custdata from allrows b where ROWNO = a.ROWNO + 2)
as LAST_NAME,
( select case when substring(custdata,1,3) = 'PID' then NULL
else custdata   end
from allrows b where ROWNO = a.ROWNO + 3)
as MIDDLE_NAME
from allrows a

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
with allpid as(
select f1.custdata,  rownumber() over(order by rrn(f1)) rang
from  yourlib.yourtable f1 where f1.custdata like 'PID%'
)
select f1.custdata as IdentificaitonId, f2.custdata as FirstName,
f3.custdata as LastName, f4.custdata as MiddleName
from allpid f1
left outer join  yourlib.yourtable f2 on f2.custdata = 'FNAME' || f1.rang
left outer join  yourlib.yourtable f3 on f3.custdata = 'LNAME' || f1.rang
left outer join  yourlib.yourtable f4 on f4.custdata = 'MNAME' || f1.rang
```

Comment: BTW When you add rrn() with a where clause, it will first apply where clause and then get RRN so in this case temp table with PIDs and row numbers as 1,2,3, etc